# Regex for string with equals sign and newline

Tags: python, regex

I have a file like below: (each record is in its own line and each line begins with a tab)

```
    one = somethinghere.maybehere
    two = 3449445949
    three = anotherhere.maybehere
    four = 443
    five = anotherhere.maybehere
    six = 43439
```

I am going to write a regex to get everything after the equals sign, for example getting `somethinghere.maybehere` or `3449445949`

I wrote a regex for each line:

```
'one\s=\s([^"]+)' 
'two\s=\s([^"]+)'
```

The problem is that it returns all other lines too and cannot detect the newline.

Then I tried this one but it cannot match anything!

```
'one\s=\s([^"]+)$\n' 
'two\s=\s([^"]+)$\n'
```

Can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Why are you using `[^"]+` here? There are no quotes in the string at all.

Comment: I am trying to learn regex and found it on this site! what can I use instead?

Comment: @user2091416 depends; what are you trying to do with your regex?

Comment: Easiest might be `(\w+) = (.*)` but not sure what you are after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have good reason to be writing 1 regex per line, modify your regex like this:

```
one\s=\s([^"\n]+)
```

This adds the newline character to the list of things not to match (along with the `"` character).

[This matches only](https://regex101.com/r/K4NLxS/1):

```
one = somethinghere.maybehere
```

and captures the `somethinghere.maybehere` into capturing group 1.

That being said, this is a minimal modification to your (mostly-working) regex to answer your question exactly; one of the other answers may have a far more efficient solution to the larger problem you're trying to solve with your code!

Answer (score 0):

This will save you **a lot of time**.  Please don't write a regex for each one.

```
from re import findall
string = """one = somethinghere.maybehere
    two = 3449445949
    three = anotherhere.maybehere  
    four = 443
    five = anotherhere.maybehere
    six = 43439"""
myValues = dict(findall(r"\s*(.*?)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*\n",string))
print(myValues["one"]) # prints somethinghere.maybehere
```

It makes all of them super easily accessible.  Refer to the last line.

Comment: Thanks. But In my case I had too extract them separately.

Comment: You could then simply check the value from myValues["one"]

Answer (score 0):

A complete walk-through could be:

```
import re

string = """
    one = somethinghere.maybehere
    two = 3449445949
    three = anotherhere.maybehere
    four = 443
    five = anotherhere.maybehere
    six = 43439
"""

rx = re.compile(r'(?P<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(?P<value>.+)')

params = {
        match.group('key'):match.group('value')
        for match in rx.finditer(string)
        }
print(params)
# {'six': '43439', 'three': 'anotherhere.maybehere', 'two': '3449445949', 'four': '443', 'five': 'anotherhere.maybehere', 'one': 'somethinghere.maybehere'}
```

This uses a dict comprehension to fill a new dictionary called `params`, see it [**working on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/9q98T0) as well [**as on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/UdrgFE/1).